# Are NuGet and Bower equivalent (JavaScript Packages)?

Tags: nuget, bower

Are Bower and NuGet equivalent when it comes to manage our JavaScript libraries?

By manage I mean "fetching and installing packages from all over, taking care of hunting, finding, downloading, and saving the stuff we're looking for. And also keeping track of these packages in a manifest file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your talking about working in a team or open source, first thing that bothers me: NuGet depends on .NET, while bower let's you chose your operating system and IDE / text editor.
NuGet forces you to use Windows (and maybe also Visual Studio 2010+), while bower runs on every system and does not depend on any of those.

> The command-line application (nuget.exe) builds and runs under Mono (version 3.2 or later) and allows you to create packages in Mono. This is especially true for Mono on Windows, but there are some known issues for Mono on Linux and OS X.

As a (front end) developer, the last thing I want to use are Windows and an IDE.

Comment: Ok, it's cleared then. Use NuGet for package dependencies related with .NET, use Bower for everything else that does not relate to .NET. Seems a good way to go. Its similar to Java environment, Maven is synonymous for NuGet and Bower must be used anyway for javascript packages. Got confused because, NuGet seems to try to rivalize with Bower... but no chance, Bower is more loosely coupled from its OS platform. Thanks!